# cygwin suddenly not working - default directory now 'cygdrive/c/Windows/system32'

Tags: cygwin

I don't know what happened.

But suddenly, when I open cygwin terminal, I now see :

```
PF@PF-PC /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
$
```

Instead of something like

```
PF@PF-PC /cygdrive/bin/
$
```

And now all my commands are not working (like 'ls', 'grep', ...).

What could have happened ?  System variables?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT : If I open cygwin by using "bash prompt here" from a windows directory, then all my cygwin works fine.
What's wrong with the normal cygwin ?

EDIT 2 : 
See my new comment. The dash (-) at the end of the shortcut is important.

Comment: Who is removing me a point ?   Can you please explain ?  This is serious question and I have tried my best to explain it. And I've beforehand search hours finding solution.

Comment: don't get too caught up in points lost.   many do it for whatever reason and unfortunately do not provide any explanation.   i am very glad you asked as i have a similar question, and will credit back that missing point!

Answer (score 1):

you surely don't have `/usr/bin` in your path anymore. Please do `echo $PATH` to see the content of path.
If you do not find `/usr/bin` go in your .bashrc and add `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`.

PS : Cygwin always go at first in `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32`, you can see it normally by doing `cd -` after the start of Cygwin to see the last path used.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I do after adding 'export $PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH.' inside 'C:\cygwin64\home\PF\.bashrc'  ?   I've restarted cygwin, and echo $PATH still doesn't show '/usr/bin'.  Also I have no such folder.  No bin directory under 'C:\cygwin64\usr'.     Same as 'C:\cygwin64\bin' ?

Comment: Also, there are multiple .bashrc files.  Adding 'export $PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH.' to 'C:\cygwin64\home\PF\.bashrc' doesn't change anything. But adding it to 'C:\cygwin64\etc\defaults\etc\bash.bashrc', and restarting cygwin, I get alot of errors like this : "bash: export: `...': not a valid identifier"

Comment: See edit, it is not `export $PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` but is  `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`. Sorry !

Comment: The final dash (-) for the shortcut was important to me : " C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico - "     What the dash mean here : "That starts mintty with a '-' (i.e. a single dash) as its only argument, which tells it to invoke the user's default shell as a login shell." - https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips